# method.bind is not a function Issue with react native 0.59.0

Tags: react-native

i am getting error from react-native after i update from 0.54.0 to 0.59.5

Getting TypeError:

```
**TypeError: method.bind is not a function. (In 'method.bind((0, _assertThisInitialized2.default)(_this))', 'method.bind' is undefined)

This error is located at:
    in Svg (at NumberCircle.js:7)
    in NumberCircle (at Overview.js:12)
    in RCTView (at View.js:45)
    in View (at Overview.js:10)
    in Overview (at LandingScreen.js:238)
```

**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it started working

i set
react-native-svg 9.3.3 in my package.json

then

```
npm install

react-native start --reset-cache
```